# Yum difference between the module with version number and without it

Tags: php, apache, centos, yum

Have a query about yum install.  what is the difference between doing

```
yum install mod_ssl 
 yum install mod24_ssl
```

If I have mod_ssl in the argument will it pick up the latest ssl packages?  How it differs from doing mod24_ssl and  how do I know which version of ssl its installing? Does it consider the dependency of apache version?  Also the same with installing php

```
yum install php
 yum install php55
```

Comment: could anyone help out regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the differences between these packages, you can use the `yum info` command like this :

```
yum info mod_ssl 
yum info mod24_ssl
```

Same with the php packages.

== Edit ==

To answer your comment : It takes the latest installable version. From the [yum man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/yum) :

> **install**
>
> Is used to install the latest version of a package or group of packages while ensuring that all dependencies are satisfied.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Does mod_ssl means yum will search for the latest mod_ssl library version for apache from repository?